# Salary re negotiation Tips

Tags: salary, job-offer, negotiation

I have been selected in MNC as a software Developer. In my initial salary discussion with HR I orally accepted his offer.  Now after research I found that offer is not best fitted for me. Can I re negotiate my salary there. I like to mention one thing here till now everything is oral. I need suggestion when I get my offer letter can I re negotiate my salary or I should accept directly that offer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The oral offer and your oral acceptance doesnt have that much importance (if any, at all). Wait until you get the written offer letter. If you like the offer and the other terms, then accept it. If you don't like the offer, then negotiate. Be prepared, though, to either accept whatever best they can offer or to decline the offer entirely.

In the meantime, keep looking for other jobs, because these "oral offers" sometimes develop this notorious disease of disappearing without any trace.

Comment: In my initial salary discussion HR asked me the figure how much I want. There I did some mistake and told XXXX amount. Then has given the figure XXXXX which is almost equal to the amount I asked. So I told Ok. Then he told me I will send you offer letter please accept it. After that I some research and found that even in that company employee of similar designation having much more salary. That’s why i  am in doubt.

Comment: Why do you make this assumption that you should be paid the same as all other employees of the company with the same designation? Things dont work that simple, your designation is not the only factor that decides your salary. Regardless, my answer still holds. Once you get the offer, you negotiate if you are not satisfied. If they increase the offer, then great. If not, either accept the offer or be ready to let it go.